# I want to create a batch file to do things depending on hibernate status

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, hibernate

I want to create a simple batch file like this:

```
SET HibernateEnabled=[getHibernationStatus]
IF HibernateEnabled==1
 ECHO do things
ELSE
 ECHO do other things
```

Furthermore I would like to not use Windows Powershell. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit

Using cmd, for in do, reg query, and find determine the hibernation registry value and act on the results with if.

CMD:

```
cmd /q /e 
FOR /f "tokens=3" %g in ('reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\ ^|FIND /i "HibernateEnabled "') do if %g==0x1 (
echo. 
echo hibernation enabled
echo do things   
) else ( 
echo.
echo hibernation disabled
echo do other things
)
```

Script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\ ^|FIND /i "HibernateEnabled "') do if %%g==0x1 (
echo. 
echo hibernation enabled
echo do things   
) else ( 
echo.
echo hibernation disabled
echo do other things
)
pause   
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also determine by `powercfg /query`:

```
powercfg /query | find /I "Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000" >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  powercfg /query | find /I "Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000" >nul 2>&1
 if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
   REM HIBERNATION IS DISABLED
  ) Else (
    REM HIBERNATION IS ENABLED
  )
)
```